# Total row doesn't work properly, Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In my Excel 2010 file and in one of its sheets I have a small table. As following, when I checked the *Total Row* option in *Table tools > Design > Table style options > Total Row* the tabled appeared as follows. But it is against of the info when I hold the mouse pointer over the *Total Row* check box because that info says: *The total row is a row at the end of the table which displays totals for each column.* But in practice it only displays the total for the last column not each column!
Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Excel only shows a sum in the right-most cell of the totals row, but you can add totals to any numeric column.

Click into the cell in the totals row to see a drop-down arrow. Click that and select what calculation you want in that column.

[image]